# In my app we are getting ANR due to parser = new ConfigXmlParser(); attaching code snippe

Tags: mfp

We are using below code in our project

private ConfigXmlParser parser;`parser = new ConfigXmlParser();
parser.parse(this);

```
public Boolean hasCordovaSplashscreen() {
    ArrayList<PluginEntry> plugins = parser.getPluginEntries();
    for (PluginEntry plugin : plugins) {
        if (plugin.pluginClass.equals("org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with IBM MQ? You should actually post the text of your code,  **not** a screen shot of the code.

Comment: Your question is lacking the detail that allows the community to help you. What result are you getting? What result were you expecting to get? What have you tried so far to narrow down the error?